# Can't use addClass on anchor?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a  problem with adding the class "active" to my first anchor in my nav (Home).

Here is my codepen - **http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/vbhDF**

Here's my **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var homeLink = $(".nav a")[0];
    console.log(homeLink);  
    homeLink.addClass("active");
    $("#home").addClass("center");  
});
```

Here's the (relevant to the question part of) my **HTML**:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="holder clearfix">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#creature">Creature</a></li>
            <li><a href="#landscape">Landscape</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not only link to the source code, but as a question should stand on its own, add it also the question body.

Comment: Thanks for editing. It was the last time (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a")[0];
```

To:

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a").first();
```

You'll want `.first()` in this case, although if you decide to target other anchors in that grouping use `.eq()`.

You were trying to use a jQuery method on a JavaScript object, hence the console error:

> "Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'addClass'"

[**Codepen here.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wFdaB)

Answer (score 3):

`$(".nav a")[0]` returns the DOM element and not a jQuery object
You should use `.first()` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
var homeLink = $("ul.nav li a").first();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, instead of adding a class to DOM element try this:

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a:eq(0)");
```

Reference: [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select a like by its index, use [jQuery .eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of bracket, else you lose the jQuery reference (and can't use jquery function like `addClass`:

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a").eq(0);
```

You can also use `.first()`, but if you want to select the second or thrid one, you'll need `.eq()`

Also, if you want to select by the `href`, it will be like that :

```
$('a[href="#home"]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Its has several options

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a")[0];  // Get first DOM element, no jquery Object

/* Add jquery function */
$(homeLink).addClass("active");
    $("#home").addClass("center");
```

or better way

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a").first();   // Get jquery Object
```

or also

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a").eq(0);      // Cero position is first element
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
var homeLink = $(".nav a:first");
```